# Redis Reactive Streams Subscriber Thread Hangs

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis

Am trying to use Spring Boot Redis Reactive Stream to subscribe to the stream as a listener.When the data is inserted into the stream listener will pass to client using GRPC stream. I have pointer which is just redis value to keep track of last record which was delivered to the client.The thread is getting blocked randomly when i set pointer to redis and getting timeout.
Mainly am using this pointer if client re-connects after sometime I wanted to deliver data which was last sent and till current data  `template.opsForValue().set(pointerKey, msg.getId().toString()) .block(Duration.ofSeconds(5));` this place thread is getting blocked

Please let me know is anything wrong in the below code. If posted 10 record to the stream I got the error after receiving 5 record.

Code

```
 public void subscribe(){

    String channelId = this.streamRequest.getTopic();
    String identifier = this.streamRequest.getIdentifier();
    boolean isNew = this.streamRequest.getNew();
    String pointerKey = channelId + "_" + identifier + "_pointer";
    
    StreamOffset<String> stringStreamOffset = StreamOffset.fromStart(channelId);
    
    if(isNew){
      // If client want to read data from the start
      // Removed the pointer
      template.opsForValue().delete(pointerKey).block();
    } else {
      String id = template.opsForValue().get(pointerKey).block();
      stringStreamOffset = id != null ? StreamOffset.create(channelId, ReadOffset.from(id)) : StreamOffset.fromStart(channelId);
    }
    
    logger.info("[SC] subscribed {}", this.streamRequest);
    Flux<ObjectRecord<String, String>> receiver = this.streamReceive.receive(stringStreamOffset);
    disposable = receiver.subscribe(msg -> {
      
      logger.info("Processing message {}", msg.getValue());
      String value = msg.getValue();
      StreamResponse streamResponse = StreamResponse.newBuilder().setData(value).build();
      
      try{
        logger.info("[SC] posting data to the grpc client topic {}", this.streamRequest);
        this.responseObserver.onNext(streamResponse);
        logger.info("[SC] Successfully posted data to the grpc client {}", this.streamRequest);
        
        logger.info("[SC] Updating pointer {}", pointerKey);
        template.opsForValue().set(pointerKey, msg.getId().toString())
            .block(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        logger.info("[SC] pointer update completed {}", pointerKey);
      
      }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.error("Error:{}", ex.getMessage());
        this.responseObserver.onError(ex.getCause());
        close();
      }
    });
  }
```

Error:

```
Name: lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1
State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync@3c9ebf7a
Total blocked: 2  Total waited: 60

Stack trace: 
java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:717)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1074)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:276)
app//reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:121)
app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection.setPointer(StreamConnection.java:68)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection.lambda$new$0(StreamConnection.java:54)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection$$Lambda$1318/0x0000000801553610.accept(Unknown Source)
app//reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.next(FluxCreate.java:154)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription.onStreamMessage(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:398)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription.access$300(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:210)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription$1.onNext(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:360)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription$1.onNext(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:351)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:345)
app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
app//io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:886)
app//io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:291)
app//io.lettuce.core.output.StreamingOutput$Subscriber.onNext(StreamingOutput.java:64)
app//io.lettuce.core.output.StreamReadOutput.complete(StreamReadOutput.java:110)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.doDecode(RedisStateMachine.java:343)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.decode(RedisStateMachine.java:295)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:841)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode0(CommandHandler.java:792)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:766)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:658)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Name: lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1
State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync@3c9ebf7a
Total blocked: 2  Total waited: 60

Stack trace: 
java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:717)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1074)
java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:276)
app//reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:121)
app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection.setPointer(StreamConnection.java:68)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection.lambda$new$0(StreamConnection.java:54)
app//ai.jiffy.message.publisher.ws.StreamConnection$$Lambda$1318/0x0000000801553610.accept(Unknown Source)
app//reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.next(FluxCreate.java:154)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription.onStreamMessage(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:398)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription.access$300(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:210)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription$1.onNext(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:360)
app//org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamReceiver$StreamSubscription$1.onNext(DefaultStreamReceiver.java:351)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:345)
app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
app//io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:886)
app//io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:291)
app//io.lettuce.core.output.StreamingOutput$Subscriber.onNext(StreamingOutput.java:64)
app//io.lettuce.core.output.StreamReadOutput.complete(StreamReadOutput.java:110)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.doDecode(RedisStateMachine.java:343)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.decode(RedisStateMachine.java:295)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:841)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode0(CommandHandler.java:792)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:766)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:658)
app//io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you block reactive streams? Do you really need reactive API if you are blocking everywhere?

Comment: Am not blocking reactive streams. am blocking opsForValue to set the value so pointer is updated before reading the next message from the stream.

Comment: ‘block()‘  is blocking operation and it should not be used if your want to make you app reactive. In your case you will block “reactive” thread ‘lettuce-nioEventLoop‘. Not sure what is your goal here but you will not get any benefits from reactive API. Consider using non-reactive API or refactor your code to define reactive flow using different operators like ‘flatMap‘